# How to fetch data from database on modal to show detail of particular click

Tags: php, mysqli, bootstrap-modal

I create product show page. Each row 4 product show. I have 7 product uploaded in database. So, if i click on particular product open the modal and show detail of product i clicked. I don't understand how fetch data on modal of particular product. Here's my code below. Please Help me.

Here i fetch data to product show.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="position-relative">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM wm_products";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        ?>
                            <!-- start team item -->
                            <div class="col-md-3 padding-15px-lr team-block text-left team-style-1 md-margin-40px-bottom wow fadeInUp">
                                <div class="agileinfo_new_products_grid">
                                    <div class="agile_ecommerce_tab_left agileinfo_new_products_grid1">
                                        <div class="hs-wrapper hs-wrapper1">
                                            <img src="products_images/<?php echo $row['pro_img']; ?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
                                        </div>
                                        <p style="height:40px;"><a href="single.html"><?php echo $row['pro_name']; ?></a></p>
                                        <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                            <p><i class="item_price"><?php echo $row['pro_price'];?></i></p>
                                            <p><a href="" class="item_add prod_detail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PRODUCT_DETAILS" dataid="<?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?>">View</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end team item -->  
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my modal to show product detail.

```
<div id="PRODUCT_DETAILS" class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">                   
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $row['pro_name'];?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body product_detail">
                    <div class="col-md-5 modal_body_left">
                        <img src="../products_images/<?php echo $row['pro_img']; ?>" alt=" " class="width-azset img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 modal_body_right">
                        <h4><?php echo $row['pro_name'];?></h4>
                        <p><?php echo $row['pro_dis'];?></p>

                        <div class="modal_body_right_cart simpleCart_shelfItem">
                            <p><i class="item_price"><?php echo $row['pro_price'];?></i></p>                            
                        </div>                  
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>                   
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="Add_Cart" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `onclick` of anchor tag  get the `dataid` in jquery  and do some ajax call with  `dataid`  and load the response content in modal body .

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using php jQuery/ajax and JavaScript:

So if you change your anchor tag to the following:

```
<p><a href="#PRODUCT_DETAILS" class="item_add prod_detail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PRODUCT_DETAILS" data-id="<?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?>">Add to cart</a></p>
```

Then get the data id from the anchor tag in question and get the relevant details for that product using jquery ajax php doing the following:

```
  $('#PRODUCT_DETAILS').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var productID= $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetchProductDetails.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{productID:productID},
            dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data)
            {   
                $('#proPrice').text(data.price);
                $('#proName').text(data.name);
                $('#proNameTitle').text(data.name);
                $('#proDesc').text(data.description);
                $('#proImage').html(data.img); 
            }
        })
     });
```

Create a php file which gets all the product details like so:

```
require 'database.php';

if (isset($_POST['productID'])) {

$productID = $_POST['productID'];

$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=:productID');
$query->execute(array(':productID' => $productID));

if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $data['description'] = $row['pro_dis'];
        $data['name'] = $row['pro_name'];
        $data['price'] = $row['pro_price'];

        $img = $row['pro_img'];

        $data['img'] = "<img src='../products_images/".$img."' alt='' class='width-azset img-responsive'>";

}
    echo json_encode($data);

}else{
    echo "<h1>" . "Error 404 Page" . "</h1>";
}
}
```

Then in your modal you can show this by doing the following:

```
<div id="PRODUCT_DETAILS" class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">                   
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 id="proNameTitle"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body product_detail">
                    <div class="col-md-5 modal_body_left">
                        <span id="proImage"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 modal_body_right">
                        <h4 id="proName"></h4>
                        <p id="proDesc"></p>

                        <div class="modal_body_right_cart simpleCart_shelfItem">
                            <p id="proPrice"></i></p>                            
                        </div>                  
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>                   
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="Add_Cart" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Slightly amended just to match for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In product display try changing data-id to href in the line below

```html
<p><a href="" class="item_add prod_detail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PRODUCT_DETAILS" dataid="<?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?>">Add to cart</a></p>
```

such that you have

```html
<p><a href="" class="item_add prod_detail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PRODUCT_DETAILS" href="#modal<?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?>">Add to cart</a></p>
```

Then for your modal update id attribute to

```html
<div id="#modal<?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?>" class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

I'm also assuming your modal display data are also inside the while statement or you have made a while statement for them.

So in the end you should have:

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="position-relative">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM wm_products";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        ?>
                            <!-- start team item -->
                            <div class="col-md-3 padding-15px-lr team-block text-left team-style-1 md-margin-40px-bottom wow fadeInUp">
                                <div class="agileinfo_new_products_grid">
                                    <div class="agile_ecommerce_tab_left agileinfo_new_products_grid1">
                                        <div class="hs-wrapper hs-wrapper1">
                                            <img src="products_images/<?php echo $row['pro_img']; ?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
                                        </div>
                                        <p style="height:40px;"><a href="single.html"><?php echo $row['pro_name']; ?></a></p>
                                        <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                            <p><i class="item_price"><?php echo $row['pro_price'];?></i></p>
                                            <p><a href="" class="item_add prod_detail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PRODUCT_DETAILS" href="#modal<?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?>">Add to cart</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end team item -->  

                            <!-- corresponding modal  -->
                            <div id="#modal<?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?>" class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">                   
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $row['pro_name'];?></h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body product_detail">
                                            <div class="col-md-5 modal_body_left">
                                                <img src="../products_images/<?php echo $row['pro_img']; ?>" alt=" " class="width-azset img-responsive">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-7 modal_body_right">
                                                <h4><?php echo $row['pro_name'];?></h4>
                                                <p><?php echo $row['pro_dis'];?></p>

                                                <div class="modal_body_right_cart simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                                    <p><i class="item_price"><?php echo $row['pro_price'];?></i></p>                            
                                                </div>                  
                                            </div>                  
                                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>                   
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="submit" name="Add_Cart" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                            <!-- corresponding modal end  -->
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```